# How to handle user input in Python?

Tags: python

I'm making a small game.
Now I need to figure out how to handle users input.

A user must be able to take or drop items.
Stating: 'TAKE item'.

The 'item' is in a list, so it can be anything.

```
        command = input("> ")
        command = command.upper()


        if self.current_room.is_connected(command):
            self.move(command)
        elif command in ['HELP', 'LOOK', 'QUIT', 'INVENTORY']:
            self.commands(command)
        elif ??? TAKE 'item'
            self.take(command)
        else:
            print("Invalid move!")
```

How do i have this code be transferred to the take method.
And how do i split those 2 word inputs?

```
def take(self, command):
    if command == 'TAKE':
        if 'item' not in self.current_room.inventory:
            print('No such item.')
        else:
            self.current_room.inventory.remove_item('item')
            self.player_inventory.add_item('item')
            print('item', 'taken.')
```

Comment: what does the self.take method do?

Comment: You could check if `command` starts with `'TAKE '` or `'DROP '` (notice the spaces at the end of the strings)

Comment: I think that you should simplify question

Comment: Either provide your entire class, or simplify the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your commands don't split the command arguments in to an arg list. This is one fairly simple way to achieve what you're looking for, by splitting into arguments before you begin your parse. This is part of a process called *[tokenizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)* in the realm of compilers.

```py
        command = input("> ")
        command = command.upper().split()

        if self.current_room.is_connected(command[0]):
            self.move(command[0])
        elif command[0] in ['HELP', 'LOOK', 'QUIT', 'INVENTORY']:
            self.commands(command)
        elif command[0] in ['TAKE', 'DROP']:
            item = command[1]
            if command[0] == 'TAKE':
                self.take(command[1])
            else:
                self.drop(command[1])
        else:
            print("Invalid move!")
```

You should be able to fairly easily handle errors in the `take` and `drop` methods. Here are a few cases you may want to check:

- displaying a message if you're not carrying the item ( when you `drop` it)
- if the item doesn't exist in the room (when you `take` it)
- if you're already carrying too much (when you `take` it)